# Entity Framework 5 Code-First dropping/recreating database when app is restarted

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm experimenting with the latest EF 5 CF (in VS2010, not VS2012). I'm generally following the MSDN EF 5.0 Quickstart: Creating a Model with Code First...

Rather than using a console app, my DbContext is in a Windows Service, which will eventually expose various data service methods by hosting a WCF Service (the client will be WPF MVVM)

In the OnStart of the Windows Service, I invoke SetInitializer, and then do a simple query to trigger initialization:

```
// Start the Windows service.
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{          
   Database.SetInitializer<MediaLibraryContext>(new MediaLibraryContextInitializer());
   using (var context = new MediaLibraryContext())
   {
      var firstMedia = (from m in context.Medias select m).FirstOrDefault();
   }
   ...
```

And EF CF creates the database from the model and seeds it, as expected.

**But when I stop/restart the Service, EF appears to delete the database and recreate it** (or perhaps it's just dropping the tables and recreating them?).  All post-initialization changes I've made to the database are gone, and only the "seed" data is present.

I've worked with EF 4.1 and 4.3, but I've never seen this behavior.  Any ideas where to look???

DadCat

EDIT: I found the problem just after posting this... the Quick start code has the database initialization strategy set to  DropCreateDatabaseAlways.

That's what I get for copy/pasting code without carefully looking at it!

DC

Comment: Your EDIT should be an answer (you can accept your own answer), or delete your question, nothing to answer here anymore, I think...

Comment: It wouldn't let me answer my own question. That's why I did the edit...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem just after posting this... the Quick start code has the database initialization strategy set to DropCreateDatabaseAlways.